# Statistical measure to find data trend

Tags: pandas, numpy, math, statistics, data-science

Im analysing a time series data where i have sales for each month for different products.  Sure it has got some patterns in trend.

I am looking for a simple measure that would tell me whether a series of numbers are increasing in order or decreasing as whole, not pairwise.

for example:

```
5, 6, 23 : Positive  
23, 5, 6 : Negative  
23, 6, 5 : Negative
```

More importantly i need the measure to be sensitive to the most recent entries i.e last observation in the list of values.

for example:

```
1,  2, 34,  3 : Negative  
1,  2, 34,  33 : Positive
```

Is there any statistical measure that can be used for this purpose or any other solutions?

Comment: We can do a weighted sum of trends. Let's say we have n values in a row. w * (elem[n] - elem[n-1]) + (1-w) * (elem[n] - elem[1]), where w belongs to [0, 1]. Higher values for w (e.g 0.8) will give a higher weight to the recent trends.                                                  Another way is do something similar to exponential smoothing -> trend[n+1] = trend[n] + α * trend[n-1] + α**2 * trend[n-2] .....